# AWS S3 automated file upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I wanted to automate the process of copying files between two S3 buckets.

scenario: whenever the same files are getting uploaded to S3(first bucket) the older versions of the file should be moved to another S3 bucket(second S3) and only the newer version file should reside in the first bucket. Please suggest to me the process of doing this

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to do this? Would you consider using [Versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/versioning-workflows.html) instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if there is a direct way, but I want to use shell scripts to achieve：

aws s3 cp s3://newfile/ s3://backupfile --recursive
aws s3 cp /Local/file s3://newfile/ --recursive

Answer (score 0):

When an object is uploaded to Amazon S3 with the same Key (filename) as an existing object, the new object will ***overwrite* the existing object**.

This can be avoided by activating **[Versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/versioning-workflows.html)** on the bucket, which will retain *all* versions of an object. So, if a new object is uploaded with the same Key, then the old object becomes a 'previous version' and is still accessible in S3. (You will pay for the storage of *all* versions.)

If your requirements are to preserve previous versions of objects, then **this should be sufficient for your need**, without having to copy the older version to a different bucket.

If you *really* wanted to do as you ask, then you would need:

- **Versioning turned on** (to preserve older versions)
- An **AWS Lambda function** that is triggered by the upload that will copy the *old* version to a different bucket and optionally delete the 'old version'
- A **plan** for what to do when there is *another* upload of the same object -- should it copy it to the 'other bucket' and overwrite the older version that is already there? It might need Versioning too!

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply:). is there any code available in python for the same to keep only the latest version and move rest all versions to different bucket.

Comment: There is no automated facility to do this. You would need to code it yourself as detailed above. However, I repeat my question, _Why_ do you want to do this? Have you considered using Versioning instead?

Comment: hi John, we don’t want old versions files to be in our main folder according to the requirement of project that’s why we want to move it to a backup folder.

Comment: Then according to the requirement of your project, you will need to implement the above process yourself. If you are having a problem with a specific step, you are welcome to create a new question with the details of your problem.